# Iphone game dev, c++ / mac comparison

Tags: iphone

Hey guys, I've done some research but still unsure.
To get into IPhone Game Dev properly do I need to use Objective C rather than C++ ? I'm happy to invest in a mac mini and want to make sure I'm using the same systems/platforms professional Iphone Dev's use. Are most of the tutorials out there in Objective C E.T.C?

Cheers!

Comment: There are a lot of options, including using languages other than Objective-C. there are even game makers that let you prepare your game in HTML and JavaScript and deploy to mobile. I have prepared a [large list of iPhone Game engines](http://mobilegameengines.com/iphone/game_engines) that might help you make a decision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's totally up to you. If you decide to write your own game engine you can do it in Objective-C or C++. IMHO there is no single proper way to do game dev. I use mac mini and do parts of my coding in c++ if I find that easier than coding in Objective-C. After all you don't want to mix engine stuff (probably using opengl) with ui stuff so your code gets separated anyway. It honestly doesn't matter what is the language of your game engine as long as you can use it on idevice and are comfortable writing in.

So to sum up, you don't have to cling to one language. Write your UI in objective-c and prepare the environment to use opengl and then write your engine in c++ if that suits you.

Comment: Hi there, thx 4 reply! Sorry I am very new to Iphone Game Dev, so the UI (I.E the menu, the buttons the user will click on in-game?) should only be written in objective-C ? Is that because the UI is done using the IPhone SDK? Alotta questions, haha, thanks :)!

And what does the game engine encapsulate? And is it smarter for me to use a open-source game-engine out there? Is writing my own a bad idea?

How can a single game, be comprised of both C++ & Objective-C code?

Comment: Ok so maybe I mixed all up a little. First things first. To use opengl in your app you have to set-up the environment. This part is done in objective-c. There is even an opengl project template in xcode if I remember well. But...uikit's controls (buttons, menus etc.) don't mix well with opengl, so it is better to make your in-game ui with opengl (HUD if you need one or some controls the player interacts with during the play).

Comment: In terms of engine, it encapsulates basically all the stuff your game needs to work properly. It processes the user input, plays sounds when necessary, generates the graphics (of course), calculates all the physics necessary for your game (collisions, dynamics), AI of computer controller opponents, all this stuff. You can modify open-sourced engine (where applicable) but commercial stuff might just have all that you need. Remember that your potential customers don't see the engine, they see the game. Writing the engine yourself is a lot of work.

Comment: sweet thx again 4 reply!! I think I will try the cocos2d game engine and start by going through a few of those tutorials and see how I go, definitely keen not to invest much time on things that have already done in open-source frameworks. Hopefully all this won't be too daunting as haven't done OpenGL in a long time haha

Answer (score 1):

The fact that OpenGL ES is written in C means you can use C, C++, Objective-C or Objective-C++ to write your game engine. So use what you're comfortable with.

Many of the books that I've seen out there assume C++, but as I say, you can do your engine in anything of the above.